# как найти в json file имя области и города по id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
json https://api.hh.ru/areas/5

у меня к примеру в базе из этого файла есть область с id=2121 b и город id=3334
var area = 2121;
var city = 3334;

//получить этот файл
var cities = fetch("https://api.hh.ru/areas/5").then(response => {
        return response.json()
    });

вызвать функцию для area, и передать в нее 
function findArea(area, cities){
    //найти в cities area 
    //вернуть имя area
}
function findCity(city, cities){
    //найти в cities city 
    //вернуть имя city
}

спасибо!
```

Comment: надо описать структуру, которая передаётся в json. хорошо, если есть пример. тогда, уверен, сами сразу сообразите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо как-то так

```
function Get(yourUrl){
    var Httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest(); // a new request
    Httpreq.open("GET",yourUrl,false);
    Httpreq.send(null);
    return Httpreq.responseText;          
}

var json_object = JSON.parse(Get('https://api.hh.ru/areas/5'));


// Поиск области по id
function findArea(area, json_object){
  for (var i=0; i<=json_object.areas.length-1; i=i+1) {
    if (json_object.areas[i].id == area) {
        return json_object.areas[i].name;
    }
  }
  return ("Не найдено")
} 

// Поиск города по id в определенной области
function findCityInArea(area, city, json_object){
  for (var i=0; i<=json_object.areas.length-1; i++) {
    if (json_object.areas[i].id == area) {
      for (var j=0; j<=json_object.areas[i].areas.length-1; j++) {
        if (json_object.areas[i].areas[j].id==city) {
          return json_object.areas[i].areas[j].name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return ("Не найдено")  
}


//Поиск города по id по всем областям
function findCity(city, json_object){
  for (var i=0; i<=json_object.areas.length-1; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<=json_object.areas[i].areas.length-1; j++) {
      if (json_object.areas[i].areas[j].id==city) {
        return json_object.areas[i].areas[j].name + " ("+json_object.areas[i].name+")";
      }
    }
  }
  return ("Не найдено")  
}


console.log(findArea(2121, json_object))
console.log(findCityInArea(2121, 3334, json_object))
console.log(findCity(3334, json_object))
```